# Can we use Foundation with HTML5Boilerplate?

Tags: css, html, html5boilerplate, zurb-foundation

My client wants me to use [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/index.php). I am habitual of [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) with [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/). I am just wondering can I use Foundation with H5BP? I will appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Why not swap out the cool stuff you want from HTML5 Boilerplate?

Comment: thanks for sharing, i've been using Bootstrap for awhile now and it's always good to have an alternative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/index.php) can be compared to [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) as similar frameworks, then [this answer](http://www.quora.com/Is-Bootstrap-a-complement-OR-an-alternative-to-HTML5-Boilerplate-or-viceversa) by H5BP developer might come useful.

Gist: **yes you can**

Comment: In that same quora question, there is answer specifically from [zurb foundation design lead response](http://qr.ae/1cDfU)

Answer (score 0):

For user who are looking for another choice here is an open source project

http://flexbox.github.io/foundation-boilerplate/